# Changing fancyfoot mid-document

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, fancyhdr

I would like to use roman page-numbering for my initial content (before TOC), and arabic page-numbering for my main content.

However, I would also like that the page numbering of the main content were displayed in a style like "Page X of Y", where X is the current page and Y is the last page, while the page numbering of the initial content is just "Page X" (otherwise it will say something like "Page ii of 23").

Can I somehow redefine the `\fancyfoot` in the middle of the document? Or do anyone have an idea to how I can achieve this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%Footer defined
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman} % Roman page-numbering for initial content
Some initial content

\newpage
Some more initial content

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic} % Arabic page-numbering for main content
Some main content

\newpage
Some more main content
\label{LastPage}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `\fancyfoot` wherever you want (better after a `\clearpage` command, of course).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage}

%Footer defined
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman} % Roman page-numbering for initial content
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
Some initial content

\newpage
Some more initial content

\clearpage % better than \newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic} % Arabic page-numbering for main content
\fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
Some main content

\newpage
Some more main content

\end{document}
```

The `lastpage` package does better than manually adding a `\label` at the end.

It's maybe better to define commands to structure the document, though.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage}

%Footer defined
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\newcommand{\frontmaterial}{%
  \clearpage
  \pagenumbering{roman}% Roman page-numbering for initial content
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}%
}
\newcommand{\mainmaterial}{%
  \clearpage
  \pagenumbering{arabic}% Arabic page-numbering for main content
  \fancyfoot[C]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}%
}

\begin{document}

\frontmaterial

Some initial content

\newpage
Some more initial content

\mainmaterial

Some main content

\newpage
Some more main content

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, exactly what I needed! :)

Comment: @ChristianP. I added a possibly better code, so you have control of what happens in the preamble, rather than somewhere in the document.

Comment: Thanks a lot :)